# Can't install my own app from Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

Not sure whether it's related to the problem or not, but this affects **only my own apps**. When I try to install any of them, it downloads twice for some reason, then I get this message:

> Can't install [APP] Try again, and if it still doesn't work, see common ways to fix this

Other people can install and use my apps with no problems.

Here's what I tried:

- I used Titanium Uninstaller to completely uninstall my app after testing it via ADB (yes it works fine with ADB and bundletools)
- I cleared google play's data and cache
- I cleared any data/cache folder related to my app
- I completely wiped system, data, cache and storage of the phone I use for testing and reinstalled the firmware, first thing I did afterwards is trying to install my app and I got the same problem.

Here's what I got from logcat: (com.shakibb.dlala is the package name for my app)

```
05-22 00:20:54.624 23836-23836/? I/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.download.DownloadBroadcastReceiver.b(1): Intent received at DownloadBroadcastReceiver
05-22 00:20:54.626 23836-23836/? I/Finsky: [1] hmr.a(59): com.shakibb.dlala: onProgress 1472622/1472622 Status: 200 URI: content://downloads/my_downloads/39.
05-22 00:20:54.634 17611-20434/? W/zipro: Error opening archive /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/files/Dlala | الدلالة : Achat Vente en Algérie ����-5.bin: Invalid file
05-22 00:20:54.638 17611-25829/? W/zipro: Error opening archive /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/files/Dlala | الدلالة : Achat Vente en Algérie ����-5.bin: Invalid file
05-22 00:20:54.658 23836-23836/? I/Finsky: [1] frp.a(11): Selecting account [aNaMyeNBhJG7ajSBD6GdsUVaT9A] for package com.shakibb.dlala. overriding=[true]
05-22 00:20:54.668 975-975/? W/StatusBar: removeFakeNotificationViews()---removeNotification for unknown pkg: com.android.providers.downloads
05-22 00:20:54.669 975-975/? I/PhoneStatusBar: updateNotificationCountChange,mLastHasNotification:true , hasActiveNotifications:true
05-22 00:20:54.691 799-1554/? I/libPerfService: perfSetFavorPid - pid:0, 0
05-22 00:20:54.707 23836-23836/? I/Finsky: [1] hmk.a(5): com.shakibb.dlala from 2 to 3.
05-22 00:20:54.715 23836-23836/? I/Finsky: [1] hmr.e(-1): com.shakibb.dlala: onComplete
05-22 00:20:54.715 23836-23836/? I/Finsky: [1] hmr.i(1): Download com.shakibb.dlala removed from DownloadQueue
05-22 00:20:54.717 288-288/? I/installd: free_cache(0) avail 8150192128
05-22 00:20:54.717 799-1026/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
05-22 00:20:54.718 799-1026/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = DJAWEB_F8826
05-22 00:20:54.719 799-1510/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
05-22 00:20:54.719 799-1510/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = DJAWEB_F8826
05-22 00:20:54.721 23836-23836/? I/Finsky: [1] kct.a(100): Prepare to copy com.shakibb.dlala (adid: com.shakibb.dlala , isid: QnPaZv5KSVC13AUwZp9Qaw) from content://downloads/my_downloads/39 (expect 1821314 bytes, isCompressed: true)
05-22 00:20:54.721 23836-23836/? I/Finsky: [1] hvz.a(7): APK integrity will be verified using [SHA-256] method
05-22 00:20:54.728 975-975/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate index=0 updateInteresting=false
05-22 00:20:54.729 1316-1762/? I/BatteryConsumeMonitor: init var lastPlugType : 2 lastBatteryChangedLevel : 87
05-22 00:20:54.732 799-820/? I/libPerfService: perfSetFavorPid - pid:23836, 5d1c
05-22 00:20:54.732 23836-23870/? W/Finsky: [410] ctj.a(1): Copy error (source-FileNotFoundException) for com.shakibb.dlala (com.shakibb.dlala): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
05-22 00:20:54.736 256-755/? E/Vold: Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.android.vending/files/
05-22 00:20:54.736 256-755/? W/Vold: Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 0
05-22 00:20:54.737 23836-23836/? W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.android.vending/files
05-22 00:20:54.737 23836-23836/? I/Finsky: [1] kct.b(174): Retry download of com.shakibb.dlala (adid: com.shakibb.dlala , isid: QnPaZv5KSVC13AUwZp9Qaw) (inhibit 1024)
05-22 00:20:54.741 23836-23836/? I/Finsky: [1] kct.a(318): Downloading full file for com.shakibb.dlala (com.shakibb.dlala)
05-22 00:20:54.742 23836-23836/? I/Finsky: [1] hmk.a(3): Duplicate state set for 'com.shakibb.dlala' (0). Already in that state
05-22 00:20:54.742 23836-23836/? I/Finsky: [1] hmr.a(38): Download com.shakibb.dlala added to DownloadQueue
05-22 00:20:54.744 23836-23836/? I/Finsky: [1] hmk.a(5): com.shakibb.dlala from 0 to 1.
```

My device is: Meizu M2 running flyme 6.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed the problem. For some reason the downloader on my phone doesn't support emojis in filenames anymore (because it worked fine before). I removed the emoji from the app title and it works fine now.